# Migrating existing ASP.NET Core 3 App to Orchard Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, orchardcore

I have a ASP.NET Core MVC Application that uses EntityFramework Core and Identity.
So far I have only 2 Connection Strings in Appsettings.json .
Context for Models and Context for Identity.
I would like to have a Database Connection string for each user group.
Does anybody have experience with Orchard Core Framework? It was linked on the Microsoft Documentation, because multi Tenant Database for each User is not supported by Identity.
Can anybody tell me if it is difficult to migrate an existing Project to this Framework?
I also read about Multi Tanent App on a blog form Gunnar Pipemann. This approach would be an alternative for me.
Maybe some of you have developed a similiar App with Asp.net Core MVC and can share their approach.

Comment: The migration would include installing the OrchardCore NuGet package in your project, enabling the features you want (like multi-tenancy) and re-configure your permissions to use Orchard's permissions. The best way to know what your migration would look like, is to create a POC from scratch with OrchardCore